# Modifying object in place javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object that looks like this:

```
  var serviceData = {};

  serviceData.energy = {commission:15.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.099, renewal: false, offset:0, rental: true}
  serviceData.homeMedia = {commission:20.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.02, renewal: false, offset:0, rental: true}
  serviceData.removal = {commission:4.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.05, renewal: false, offset:2, rental: true}
  serviceData.storage = {commission:6.00, retention:0.09, conversion:0.01, renewal: true, offset:2, rental: true}
  serviceData.homeContents = {commission:50.00, retention:0.55, conversion:0.40, renewal: true, offset:0, rental: false}
```

I want to loop over the `serviceData` and if an item's property `rental` is false I want to remove that item from `serviceData` without actually modifying the `serviceData` object. In other words, create a new object minus the 'removed' item.

How can I do this???

Comment: Did you try using `delete` ... `delete serviceData.homeContents;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate the object keys and only set the ones you want in the new object:

```js
var serviceData = {};

serviceData.energy = {commission:15.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.099, renewal: false, offset:0, rental: true}
serviceData.homeMedia = {commission:20.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.02, renewal: false, offset:0, rental: true}
serviceData.removal = {commission:4.00, retention:0.00, conversion:0.05, renewal: false, offset:2, rental: true}
serviceData.storage = {commission:6.00, retention:0.09, conversion:0.01, renewal: true, offset:2, rental: true}
serviceData.homeContents = {commission:50.00, retention:0.55, conversion:0.40, renewal: true, offset:0, rental: false}

var filtered = {};
for(var key in serviceData) {
  if(serviceData[key].rental) {
    filtered[key] = serviceData[key];
  }
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(filtered, '\n'));
```

Note that the new object points to the same items ("sub-objects"), it's a shallow copy.

Comment: pretty much had this on my screen but couldn't quite get there. thanks for this

Answer (score 1):

First `Object.assign(...)` to copy the whole object, then use a "filter" function to sort out entries based on your rule.

Or use a `map`function to return values based on your rule, then use "filter" to sort out all `null` entries.

Just as a hint to have a starting point…

Comment: my initial thought was to filter but i don't know how to do that on an object literal

Answer (score 1):

I like using [lodash library](https://lodash.com/docs#omit) for strange manipulations :)

```
var newObj = _.omit(serviceData, function(property) {
    return !property.rental;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`for-in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and ignore the key of the item with a `false` rental.

```
function copyData(obj, ignoreKey) {
  var copiedObj = {};
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (key === ignoreKey) {
      continue;
    }
    copiedObj[key] = obj[key];
  }
  return copiedObj;
}
var newObject = copyObj(serviceData, 'homeContents');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery each method:

```
var res={};
    $.each(serviceData, function( index ) {
  if(serviceData[index].rental)
   res[index] = serviceData[index]
})
```

[pen](http://codepen.io/maio/pen/wMWRyy)

Comment: Why would you use jQuery for this?

Comment: @JimboJonny with JQuery each method you can iterate over object properties as if it was an array  ( the method corresponds to [].forEach() ), it's just a way of abstracting the for-in loop

Comment: @maioman - But there's zero need for an index here, so why not just use a for-in loop? Even when you have jQuery already in a project there's no sense in using it in places where it doesn't even provide an advantage. It's even significantly more verbose and complex to write, requiring callback anonymous functions and such.

Comment: @JimboJonny this is a simple case, but using a forEach mehod on an object is quite cool ..